# Vtreat problem in R running categorical cross-frame experiment

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I am trying to run `mkCrossFrameCExperiment` in the `Vtreat` package in R.

It works well enough when the outcome target is simple (integers) but when you have more complex data, it returns:

> Error in designTreatmentsC(dframe, varlist, outcomename,
> outcometarget,  :    dframe[[outcomename]]==outcometarget must vary

I assume there is some algorithm that can't find a solution - presumably, this can be tuned but I don't know how to do it.  If you can make any suggestions, I would appreciate it.  The code is below but isn't helpful.  I have also pasted the snapshot of the data that I am using.

```
  unpack[
    treatmentsC = treatments,
    bike.train.workTreated = crossFrame
  ] <- mkCrossFrameCExperiment(
    dframe = bike.train.work,
    varlist = setdiff(colnames(bike.train.work), 'logcount'),
    outcomename = 'logcount',
    outcometarget = TRUE,
    verbose = FALSE
  )
```

---

For what it's worth, I found a good blog online at http://uc-r.github.io/gbm_regression that answered my question.  I couldn't make the categorical experiment work (mkCrossFrameCExperiment), but the treatment plan in the blog produced the desired result.